# pyautogui.moveTo() failing sometimes and I have no idea why

Tags: python, pyautogui

**I included the whole loop, but the part I'm talking about is the third paragraph.** I have this loop, where it clicks on something, and then it moves the mouse back to wherever it was, to not interrupt the user while this thing is running. However, the pyautogui.MoveTo() call seems to be getting skipped sometimes?

```
while unlim or intFTC > 0:

    # switch to program, do thing, and switch back to current window
    current_win = gw.getActiveWindow().title
    win = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('World of Warcraft')[0]
    win.activate()
    pyautogui.press(input_key)
    win = gw.getWindowsWithTitle(current_win)[0]
    win.activate()

    # find and click thing
    bx, by = thing_finder(x, y, x1, x2, y1, y2)
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.2, 0.6))
    current_x, current_y = pyautogui.position()
    current_win = gw.getActiveWindow().title
    pyautogui.moveTo(bx, by)
    pyautogui.rightClick()

    # send mouse back to original position
    while pyautogui.position() != (current_x, current_y):
        pyautogui.moveTo(current_x, current_y)
        print('::', pyautogui.position())

    # return to og window
    win = gw.getWindowsWithTitle(current_win)[0]
    win.activate()

    window.refresh()
    stop()
    time.sleep(random.uniform(1.5, 2))
    runs += 1
```

**So in the third chunk commented "send mouse back to original position,"** it doesn't always work. The current_x, and current_y are always correct, but it won't move the mouse to those coordinates. I thought the while loop would fix it, but it still doesn't always work which boggles my mind, because how does it get out of the while loop without moving the mouse? Thank you for reading.

Is it simply a case of not enough pause time? I have the time between pyautogui calls set to 0.001, but I figured it would slow down if it had to, not skip commands.

Answer (score 0):

The loop does not make sense, you should send the command `pyautogui.moveTo(current_x, current_y)` and it should work. That condition can lead to some errors.